# How to iterate and get all user name from session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using tomcat server.
When the application has to access by multiple users. all user details are stored in session only.
In some situation I have to get all user's detail.
How can iterate and get all users detail from that session.

Answer (score 3):

Just collect and store all logins in the application scope then. Easiest would be to let the `User` object which represents the logged-in user implement `HttpSessionBindingListener`. You only need to prepare a `Set<User>` in the application scope (as a `ServletContext` attribute).

```
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.remove(this);
    }

    // Don't forget to override equals() and hashCode() as well.
}
```

This way, whenever you login the user as follows

```
User user = userService.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    // ...
}
```

then the `valueBound()` will be called. Whenever you logout the user by removing the attribute or invalidating the session or let the session expire, then `valueUnbound()` will be called.

The `ServletContext` attribute is of course just available in all servlets and JSPs.